# Async task with SimpleCursorList (Android sql select)

Tags: android, listactivity, simplecursoradapter

I'm relatively new to Android but I just cant google this. I have following situation:

1. quite large SQL db on android (need to select and load about 2000 records to ListActivity)
2. I use SimpleCursorAdapter so far BUT... it doesn't allow me to load data asynchronously with AsyncTask (SimpleCursorAdapter has no "add()" as e.g. ArrayAdapter does)
3. I know how to make it work with ArrayAdapter but then I lose the ID attribute every time the time is clicked and I want to do it the "clean" way and keep the id (not save it some place hidden)

===> For now user has to wait till all db output is parsed into GUI, it takes some time. How can I fix it to make it run faster ? I need something like SimpleCursorAdapter.add(item) or extend it but not sure ...
thnx

Comment: #3. The getItemId method in ArrayAdapter is there for a reason. You don't have to do any hidden trickery to save the ID of a row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider having some pagination mechanism, not loading everything in an ArrayAdapter but better, returning a simpleCursorAdapter with just a subset of size N of your records. When the user will reach the last row, display a button to increase N and refetch the data from your database.